# PayPal IPN with fsockopen returns NULL

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, fsockopen

I'm trying to set up the PayPal IPN on my web application, I copied from PayPal's documentation on an example PHP snippet which is found [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/ipn-codesamples-pop-outside#php).

However, when I'm testing with the PayPal's sandbox, sending an IPN with the simulator which is found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_ipn-link-session).

Now, when PayPal sends the IPN, I log the actions and data of the IPN, when trying to open an connection with `fsockopen`, it is `NULL` when I do `var_export` on it.

I don't understand why it's not going any further with the code when the `fsockopen` connection is `NULL`.

I'm using Codeigniter for my application, and this is the part of the code that fails:

```
if($this->uri->segment(3) == 'ipn')
{
    $error_msg = '';

    $error_msg .= " initiated ";

    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    $error_msg .= " \n\n req: " . var_export($req, true);

    foreach($this->input->post() as $key => $value) 
    {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&" . $key . "=" . $value;
    }

    $error_msg .= " \n\n req: " . var_export($req, true);

    $header = '';
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $error_msg .= " \n\n headers: " . var_export($header, true);

    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    $error_msg .= " \n\n fp: " . var_export($fp, true);
```

I use `$error_msg` to log the data, this is an example what is logged:

```
 initiated  

 req: 'cmd=_notify-validate' 

 req: 'cmd=_notify-validate&test_ipn=1&payment_type=echeck&payment_date=17%3A30%3A40+Jan+03%2C+2012+PST&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123%2C+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=TESTSELLERID1&residence_country=US&item_name=something&item_number=DX4WYSur44CQICgO2lC%2FB10NmdaiPNH3xPZXQNAlfrEqpse0xnime22zaNXDFgbRrOL4Xsz4emkhqFw4JhOSHzCtaHt9%2B0p9p8xW6R71PVbFXNyEVjkPeHNdQm32PJg&quantity=1&shipping=3.04&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&txn_type=web_accept&txn_id=4014130&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&charset=windows-1252&verify_sign=An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-AN8d2a.xggmx9Dn4AgHpvPHJHTAp' 

 headers: 'POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 969

' 

 fp: NULL
```

As you can see `$fp` is returning `NULL` on the last line of the logged data. Is there any idea why this is happening?

I can confirm I have OpenSSL enabled and installed on my server:

[image]

EDIT: Just tested `fsockopen` on port 80 to `google.com`, I still get `NULL` with no error number or message. So this problems occurs to every URL.

EDIT #2: Tested on my server by doing this:

```
fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30)
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr:443 (php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Comment: Is openSSL support enabled on your server?

Comment: Use `var_dump` to check instead of `var_export` as `var_export` returns "a parsable string representation of a variable". So in short, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: check if outbound connections can be created by your server. try pinging google.com from the command line. It may be a firewall issue.

Comment: From the documentation: If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE, it is an indication that the error occurred before the connect() call. This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket.

Comment: @Darhazer Pinging google.com seems fine. What should to fix fsockopen?

Comment: please enable error_reporting / display_errors and check for any warning, produced by fsockopen

Comment: You should pass only ssl://www.paypal.com only to fsockopen, the rest goes to the GET http header. Only the host, without path should be provided. Please retry with the original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful of `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` this will block all external POSTS as they will not come with a `CSRF token`, I've had this with my paypal IPN before, I needed to enable a crude but effective way to get the callback (in config.php):

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/paypal') === FALSE) {
  // disable CSRF for the /paypal 
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
} else {
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
```

I'm guessing this could be an issue, you would get `null` as no data would be captured as CI reviews your `$_POST/$_GET` vars for security reasons.

*If I misunderstood your question and am way off track, just let me know via a comment.*

Answer (score 3):

If anyone else is having the same problem, try using HTTPS instead of SSL

```
$fp = fsockopen ('https://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

And if your testing on Paypals Sandbox use:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Check List**

1. ***sandbox url:***  "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
2. like @jakub says CSRF must be disabled for your paypal controller
3. IPN wont validate on localhost, however you should still get vars back.
4. **var_dump**(fsockopen ('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30));
5. **var_dump**($_POST);

Comment: `var_dump(fsockopen..` return `resource(6) of type (stream)` , but my code still didn't works .

Answer (score 0):

The variables `$errno` and `$errstr` probably hold the reason for the failure. Echo them out with your error message.

Comment: I get `0` for `$errno` and `''` for `$errstr` when using `var_export` on them.

Comment: It's peculiar. That suggests no error. The other odd thing is when there's an error, fsockopen should return `false` not `null`. Can you try opening a connection on port 80 (just to google.com or something) to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hmm, `google.com` at port `80` still returns `NULL` with no error number and message.